# Runtime error in GoogleMap app

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

I am writing an app with GoogleMaps. I run it on emulator now.
The layout below works good with app. The map was drawn okay.
I would like to have some additional TextViews and buttons on the screen with the map.
But I have runtime error, if I add second TextView or button to my XML.
If I add them inside of some LinearLayout, I also get error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/backNormal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='My Text'
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/text_style_title"
        />
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/backNormal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error text is below:

```
3459-3459/moorlakgames.packet1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: moorlakgames.packet1, PID: 3459
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{moorlakgames.packet1/moorlakgames.packet1.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
```

As I said it works with one TextView in layout, but does not work with two TextViews.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/backNormal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text='My Text'
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/text_style_title"/>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backNormal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unforunately it does not work if I add second TextView just after first or inside of LineraLayout below.

Comment: post your layout.xml file

Comment: It is in my start message above. I suspect other elements in layout  with fragment are prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

For future cases, use indentation, it will make your life easier.

In case the above XML is your entire layout, you haven't closed your outer `LinearLayout` which may cause the `LayoutInflater` to inflate an empty `View` which causes you to get `NullPointerException` when executing

```
((MapFragment)findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: Sorry, not understood. findViewById does not work. I use  map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); As I said it works with one TextView, not with two of more elements.

Comment: I suspect it is prohibited to use buttons and other elements in layout with fragment.

Comment: They are permitted, it's not the problem. Do you inflate this layout via `Activity`'s `setContentView(int resourceId)` method?

Comment: Yes. Of course I use first this line:  setContentView(R.layout.page_one); Then map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); It is strange that everything okay with only on textView in layout